# How is this switch statement evaluated?

Tags: java, switch-statement

How does the compiler interpret this switch statement? I assume the contents inside the switch statement is (41), so why does it go to case 2?

```
    int i = 4;
    int j = 2;

    switch(i++-j) {         //switch is evaluted to be (41)??
    case 3: i++; break;
    case 1: j++; break;
    case 2: j+=2; break;
    case 5: i+=2; break;
    default: i +=5; break;
    }

    System.out.println(i);  //Prints out 4
    System.out.println(j);  //Prints out 5
```

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate what language this is. (I *think* it's Java, but I don't want to assume.)

Comment: Okay I will do, in principle I was mainly asking about how the switch statement was evaluated which should be independent of most languages

Comment: Perhaps it should be, but it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Break it down:

```
i++-j
```

`++` has higher precedence than `-` so that's:

```
(i++)-j
```

The `++` is the postfix increment — it'll evaluate to the value of `i` before the increment. The initial value of `i` is 4 so that's:

```
4-j
```

`j` is `2` so the expression evaluates as `4-2 = 2`.

`i` has been incremented so now has the value `5`; `j` is modified by the code in the switch statement.

Comment: ahh thanks got it! For some reason my mind tricked me (as I immediately thought it was --)!

Answer (score 1):

through initialization

```
i=4;
j=2; 

switch(i++-j) {  // Expression evaluates as 4-2 = 2.
    // new value for i=5 since i++ executed
    case 3: i++; break; // skipped
    case 1: j++; break; // skipped
    case 2: j+=2; break; // Executed, hence  evaluates as 2+2 = 4.
    case 5: i+=2; break; // Skipped
    default: i +=5; break; // Skipped
    }

    System.out.println(i);  // Prints out 5
    System.out.println(j);  // Prints out 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In the switch condition the value of the expression will be 4 - 2 = 2.

Then, after that value is used, i becomes 5.

Then, the case 2: will get executed, j = 2, j += 2 will be 4.

So, the output would be:

5

4